# What is a Mirage's maximum level?

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

I have been playing for quite a while now,  about 45 hours and some of my Mirages are getting towards level 50.

What is the highest level a Mirage can reach?

Answer (score -1):

The highest level appears to be 99 based on what i read [**here**](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168651-world-of-final-fantasy/74504533?jumpto=6). 
 However, it could be 100 also.

Comment: If you could add a few more sources, and pick either 99 or 100, I could accept this :)